# Why does my CAM deployment stay in Progress?

Tags: cloud-automation-manager

In a fresh CAM installation.  I have created a Cloud Connection to VMware vSphere. In VMware I did create a VM running Ubuntu 16.04 with internet access. In CAM I deployed template "Clone IBM-AutomationContentHub and IBM-CAMHub-Open"

The deployment stays in Progress. The Log File tab keeps repeating the messages:

```
...
null_resource.clone_git: Still creating... (18h58m22s elapsed)
null_resource.clone_git: Still creating... (18h58m32s elapsed)
null_resource.clone_git: Still creating... (18h58m42s elapsed)
```

Where should I look to further investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional information would be to go onto the VM which you have created and run the command, while the machine is hung in the “Still creating” phase :

```
ps -ef | egrep -C10 installation
```

Most likely it is one of these issues which you are seeing:

- user does not have passwordless sudo, verify by issuing sudo cat /etc/sudoers, if you are prompted for a password, you will need to, eg: https://askubuntu.com/questions/239432/enable-passwordless-sudo-as-a-specific-user.
- It may also be a case, where the user does not have sudo privileges, you wil need to have that user added to /etc/sudoers
- name server is not setup the machine, verify by issuing : ping github.com, if you fail to resolve that host, you will need to setup a name server.
- Otherwise, if the curl or git commands are not installed on the machine, it may be an issue with the apt mirror. Check to see if the commands are machine: which git and which curl, if one is missing, run: sudo apt-get install curl or sudo apt-get install git … NOTE: see the first step about the sudo issue. (edited)